# UIButton on horizontal UIScrollView issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have two ViewController, "firstVC" and "secondVC".
I want to create an horizontal paginated Scrollview, keeping the two viewControlles separated: so I create a new ViewController, "HomePage", where I create the scrollview and I add fisrtVC and secondVC.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    self.firstVC = [[firstVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstVC" bundle:nil];
    self.secondVC = [[secondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondVC" bundle:nil];

    //setup frame
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    self.firstVC.view.frame = frame; //this is useless, I know... it's just for understand what I'm doing

    frame.origin.x = 320;
    self.secondVC.view.frame = frame;

    //add the VC to the scrollView
    [self.scrollview addSubview:self.firstVC.view];
    [self.scrollview addSubview:self.secondVC.view];

    //setup the scrollView
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640 , frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    self.scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
    self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
}
```

HomePage is inside an UINavigationController; FirstVC and SecondVC has more custom (with image) UIButton. 
Each button should push a new ViewController on the nagivationController: in order to do it, FirstVC and SecondVC has a weak reference to HomePage, so they can call

```
[self.homePage.navigationController pushViewController:abc animated:YES];
```

Everything works, but I'm having two problems:

1) if a button is connected with an IBAction, but the method is empty, when I push the button I can see the picture highlighted. 
If the method is not empty (because, of course, it has to do something!) the button calls instantly the method, so there is no highlight! 
It seems that the method is called not when the user remove the finger from the button (as it should works), but in the moment where he touches the screen.
This problem, I think, is related to the second one:

2) Because of this, it's very difficult to scroll the scrollView (from left to right and vice versa) because a lot of times it calls the methods connected with the buttons...

What I want is something like the AppStore on the mobile version: for example in "top purchased" you can push on an icon AND THEN scroll the view. If I try to do it the button is instantly pressed!

Comment: for which button event you wired your IBAction?

Comment: FirstVC has 3 buttons: each button has its IBAction, which call [self.homepage.navigationController pushViewController:anotherVC animated:YES];. The same thing for secondVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `UIButton` control event to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Comment: Ooooops!!!! Damn it, XCode auto-completion!!! They were setted-up with `UIControlEventTouchDown`!!! Thanks!